# Do topic callbacks and timer callbacks run in the same thread?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The title says it all actually. I wonder whether I need to protect my subscription callbacks from my timer callbacks with a mutex:

```
eventSubscriber = nh.subscribe("my_topic", 1, &MyNodeClass::topicCallback, this);
timer           = nh.createTimer(my_period_, boost::bind(&MyNodeClass::timerCallback, this, _1));
```

Can `topicCallback` and `timerCallback` be executed in parallel?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240388/do-topic-callbacks-and-timer-callbacks-run-in-the-same-thread?/) by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 789 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, `topicCallback` and `timerCallback` cannot be executed in parallel, as long as you are using single-threaded spinning. For example, if you are using an [`AsyncSpinner`](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1AsyncSpinner.html), callbacks are called from multiple threads and additional care needs to be taken.

Timer (and topic/message) callbacks are serviced when calling `spin()` or `spinOnce()` (assuming you are not using some custom `CallbackQueue` handling).

Refer to http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning for more details. ;-)

---

Originally posted by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) with karma: 100 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3